# Apply 2 preg_split with regex to text

Tags: php, regex, expression, preg-match, preg-split

Context:
I have to split an email with several customers’ reservations details that is received every day, with a set of rules. This is an example of the email:

```
A N K U N F T   11.08.15
*** NEUBUCHUNG ***
 11.08.15  xxx  xxx  X3 2830  14:25   17:50
 18.08.15  xxx  xxx  X3 2831  18:40
 F882129  dsdsaidsaia
 F882129  xxxyxyagydaysd
sadsdsdsdsadsadadssda
sadsdsdsdsadsadadssda
**«CUT HERE2»**


A N K U N F T   18.08.15
*** NEUBUCHUNG ***
 11.08.15  xxx  xxx  X3 2830  14:25   17:50
 18.08.15  xxx  xxx  X3 2831  18:40
 F881554  ZXCXZCXCXZCCXZ
 F881554  xcvcxvcxvcvxc
 F881554  xvcxvcxcvxxvccvxxcv

**«CUT HERE»**


11.08.15  xxx  xxx  X3 2830  14:25   17:50
 18.08.15  xxx  xxx  X3 2831  18:40
 F881605  xczxcdfsfdsdfs
 F881605  zxccxzxzdffdsfds

**«CUT HERE»**
```

So it basically has to be cut whenever the last F999999 appears (where 9 can be any digit), because F999999 is the reservation code.*
I inserted the text: «CUT HERE» just to better understand where to cut.

*NOTE: reservation code may have the following formats: F999999, A999999, E999999 or 999999.

So I apply a working preg_split with the following regex:

```
Regex1 = "/(?:\\s(F|A|E)?\\d{6}\\s?+.*?\r\n\\s?\r\n)\\K//ms";
```

However sometimes I have to cut where «CUT HERE2» appears, because sometimes there is some text after the reservation code delimiter.

So I created this regex:

```
Regex2 = "/^\h*(F|A|E)?\d{6}.*?\R{2}\K/ms"
```

Yet, I sometimes have this format (newlines between, F999999 of the same reservation), making my previous regex (regex2) cut where it says «NOT CUT HERE»:

```
A N K U N F T   11.08.15
*** NEUBUCHUNG ***
 11.08.15  xxx  xxx  X3 2830  14:25   17:50
 18.08.15  xxx  xxx  X3 2831  18:40
 F882129  dsdsaidsaia

<<NOT CUT HERE>>

 F882129  xxxyxyagydaysd
sadsdsdsdsadsadadssda
sadsdsdsdsadsadadssda
**«CUT HERE»**


A N K U N F T   18.08.15
*** NEUBUCHUNG ***
 11.08.15  xxx  xxx  X3 2830  14:25   17:50
 18.08.15  xxx  xxx  X3 2831  18:40
 F881554  ZXCXZCXCXZCCXZ

<<NOT CUT HERE>>

 F881554  xcvcxvcxvcvxc
 F881554  xvcxvcxcvxxvccvxxcv

**«CUT HERE»**


11.08.15  xxx  xxx  X3 2830  14:25   17:50
 18.08.15  xxx  xxx  X3 2831  18:40
 F881605  xczxcdfsfdsdfs
 F881605  zxccxzxzdffdsfds

**«CUT HERE»**
```

I just want it to cut where **«CUT HERE»** appears.

This error happens for example:

```
***NEUBUCHUNG ***
 23.02.17  DUS  FNC  DE 1414  12:05   15:10
 09.03.17  FNC  DUS  DE 1415  16:40
 FNC011  Enotel Baia                  9360-215 Ponta do Sol
  1  DZ Typ I Meerblick 2Erw.         Frühstück
 am 03.10.16  CRS: MX  - PNR: 1290689
 Fluggeber: Condor Flugdienst / PNR: 1290689  Frühbucher 10%  inkl. Reiseleitung  und Transfer ab/bis   
 A025808  HERR Berg, Ulrich               62


<<NOT CUT HERE>
 
Anfrage.
 A025808  FRAU Berghaus, Petra            58
    
 **«CUT HERE»**

***S T O R N O **
 04.10.16 STR  X3 2810
 11.10.16 FNC  STR  X3 2811  18:15
FNC036    The Flame Tree               Funchal
 1  DZ Meerblick 2Erw.                 H
A987025  FRAU  BURG, GERTRUD          *** STORNO ***              O


<<NOT CUT HERE>>

 
A987025  HERR  BURG, WALTER           *** STORNO ***              O
    
**«CUT HERE»**

***ÄNDERUNG ***
NEU:01.11.16 FRA  X3 2806  13:35   16:50
08.11.16 FNC  FRA  X3 2807  17:40
   FNC813    Golden Residence/Wanderk. 9000-105 Funchal
 1  Suite seitl. Meerblick 3Erw.       F
A982512 FRAU   KROST, SIMONE
Frühbucher 15%


<<NOT CUT HERE>>
 
inkl. Reiseleitung
und Transfer ab/bis 
Im Reisepreis bereits enthalten: Drei
geführte Wanderungen (1 Ganztags- und 2
Halbtagswanderungen) inkl. aller
Transfers.

**«SHOULD CUT HERE»**

***ÄNDERUNG ***
ALT:01.11.16 FRA  X3 2806  13:35   16:50
08.11.16 FNC  FRA  X3 2807  17:40
FNC813   Golden Residence/Wanderk. 9000-105 Funchal
 1  Suite seitl. Meerblick 3Erw.   F
   A982512      HERR KROST, SIMONE 
    
**«CUT HERE»**


 25.04.17  DRS  FNC  ST 1602  13:25   17:15
 09.05.17  FNC  DRS  ST 1607  00:00
 FNC076  Baia Azul                    9004-530 Funchal
  1  DZ Typ I Meerblick 2Erw.         Halbpension
 am 03.10.16  CRS: MX  - PNR: 15326821
 Fluggeber: alltours / PNR: 15326821
 inkl. Reiseleitung
 und Transfer ab/bis Flughafen
 A025986  HERR Schulze, Steffen           55
 A025986  FRAU Schulze, Kerstin           54

**«CUT HERE»**

***S T O R N O **
 13.11.16 FRA  X3 2806
 20.11.16 FNC  FRA  X3 2807  17:35
FNC096    Pestana Village & Miramar    Funchal
 1  Studio 2Erw.                       H
A976918  FRAU  HEBING, BETTINA        *** STORNO ***              O

<<NOT CUT HERE>> 
 
A976918  HERR  HEBING, LUDGER         *** STORNO ***              O

  **«CUT HERE»**
```

I put «NOT CUT HERE» where it splits but shouldn’t. I put: **«SHOULD CUT HERE»** where it should cut. And i put «CUT HERE» were it cuts correctly.

Comment: Try `preg_split('~^\h*F\d{6}.*?\R{2}\K~sm', $input)`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/lU2bW6/1). Pay attention to `~sm` modifiers. See https://ideone.com/LGuxuu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
'~^\h*F\d{6}.*?\R{2}\K~sm'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lU2bW6/1)

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `\h*` - 0+ horizontal whitespaces
- `F\d{6}` - `F` + 6 digits
  -`.*?` - any 0+ chars up to the *first*
- `\R{2}` - 2 linebreaks
- `\K` - and omit the whole match text.

See [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/LGuxuu):

```
$re = '~^\h*F\d{6}.*?\R{2}\K~ms'; 
$str = "A N K U N F T   11.08.15\n*** NEUBUCHUNG ***\n 11.08.15  xxx  xxx  X3 2830  14:25   17:50\n 18.08.15  xxx  xxx  X3 2831  18:40\n F882129  dsdsaidsaia\n F882129  xxxyxyagydaysd\nsadsdsdsdsadsadadssda\nsadsdsdsdsadsadadssda\n\nA N K U N F T   18.08.15\n*** NEUBUCHUNG ***\n 11.08.15  xxx  xxx  X3 2830  14:25   17:50\n 18.08.15  xxx  xxx  X3 2831  18:40\n F881554  ZXCXZCXCXZCCXZ\n F881554  xcvcxvcxvcvxc\n F881554  xvcxvcxcvxxvccvxxcv\n\n\n11.08.15  xxx  xxx  X3 2830  14:25   17:50\n 18.08.15  xxx  xxx  X3 2831  18:40\n F881605  xczxcdfsfdsdfs\n F881605  zxccxzxzdffdsfds\n\n"; 
print_r(preg_split($re, $str));
```

Comment: Sometimes there are newlines ( 5, 6 depends) between F999999 of the same group. like here: https://regex101.com/r/lU2bW6/2

Comment: Should I delete the newlines or is there a regex form of capturing?

Comment: Is the split point right before `A N K U N F T` that is at the beginning of a line?

Comment: yes, but sometimes there isnt ankufbt, like in the third and Last group.

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot understand what locations you need to match in [this fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/lU2bW6/2).

Comment: Try [`'~(?:^\h*F\d{6}.*(?:\s*F\d{6}.*)*)+(?:\R\h*){2,}\K~m'`](https://regex101.com/r/lU2bW6/5).

Comment: Hi, its better, but sometimes cuts before line. Like here: https://regex101.com/r/lU2bW6/6. 
For example ( should cut after line, not before):
512550   HERR  NEMITZ, ANDREAS        *** STORNO ***              O

A985935  HERR  STOLLE, JOERG          *** STORNO ***              O

Comment: I updated regex, because F999999 can be a A999999, E999999 and 999999.

Comment: Sorry, it is becoming unwieldly. Just FYI: you put a `?` after `()` making it *optional*. Did you mean `'~(?:^\h*[FAE]\d{6}.*(?:\s*[FAE]\d{6}.*)*)+(?:\R\h*){2,}\K~m'`?

Comment: No, it is on purpose. Because the code can be only 999999 (six digits). in this example: 512550

Comment: I have come up with a regex based on the line with intial 3 `*`s: [`'~^(?!\A)(?=\*{3})|\z~gm'`](https://regex101.com/r/lU2bW6/8).

Comment: But not always starts with 3 *, e.g: F881605 , A025986 ( added this in last example )

Comment: Another try [`'~(?:^\h*[FAE]?\d{6}.*(?:\R\h*\S.*)*(?:\s*\R\h*(?:[FAE]?\d{6}.*(?:\R\h*\S.*)?)*)*)+(?:\R\h*){2,}\K~m'`](https://regex101.com/r/lU2bW6/9).

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/lU2bW6/11  I tried with my examples and it cuts where it says «NOT CUT HERE» and it shouldnt..this is very dificult, as you say it doesnot have a clear delimiter, I know by common sense, and seeing the last [FAE]\d{6} pattern and the begining of a new one...

Comment: It helped in some situations. however is it possible to correct this: https://regex101.com/r/ukAgap/1